# Odd flow in shacharis of Shabas

Tags: shabbat, shemoneh-esrei, shacharis-morning-prayer, parashat-ki-tisa, aseres-hadibros

The central benediction of the morning *amida* prayer on the sabbath reads as follows (in loose translation):

> Moses… stood before You on Mt. Sinai. He brought down [from the mountain], by hand, two stone tablets, in which were written the safeguarding of the sabbath; and thus is written in Your Torah:
>
> "The Israelites shall safeguard the sabbath, making it a covenant eternal, for their generations. Between Me and the Israelites it is a symbol forever …."
>
> You didn't give it to other nations of the world …

It flows — kind of. It goes from "the tablets had safeguarding the sabbath" to a passage from Scripture about safeguarding the sabbath; that passage mentions the special bond between God and us, and we continue discussing that bond. Okay. But it seems there's a sharp turn between discussion of the tablets and the quotation from Scripture. You'd expect, after that intro about the tablets, to be presented with a quotation from the tablets. But no: the quotation is from elsewhere. So, yes, I see its relevance, but it still strikes me as odd. It seems kinda like saying "I was reading Mi Yodeya, it's a great site, has the best content, and I saw there the most wonderful thing about the exodus from Egypt, and some other site has this: the exodus was…". Are there any explanation offered of this oddity?

Comment: Doesn't it have to do something with the avoidance of the Ten Commandments in the liturgy due to _minim?_ Though in the _kiddush_ we use it...

Comment: It might be significant that the verse immediately after those quoted is וַיִּתֵּ֣ן אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֗ה כְּכַלֹּתוֹ֙ לְדַבֵּ֤ר אִתּוֹ֙ בְּהַ֣ר סִינַ֔י שְׁנֵ֖י לֻחֹ֣ת הָֽעֵדֻ֑ת...